# Recursive Neo4j query from end to origin, naming the step-pairs in between

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a quite simple structure in my Neo4j database:
DataProducts -> Table -> Columns

[image: match(n) return n]

A column has an outgoing relationship to another column named TRANSFORMATION, with a type and a code property.

I need to be able to find the path of sources of a column recursively back to its origin. So for example, let's say we have a column "A" from table "X", of DataProduct "1", which has as a source column "B" from table "Y" of DataProduct "2" and "B" has as a source column "C" from table "Z" of DataProduct "3". So I want to be able to start at the end of a chain and the query should find the path back recursively to the origin of the source which has no further upstream sources.

The query should return a result of:

| Target DataProduct | Target Table | Target Column | Source DataProduct | Source Table | Source Column | Relationship type | Relationship Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | A | 2 | Y | B | simple | insert |
| 2 | Y | B | 3 | Z | C | function | concat |

Now this query is getting in the neighbourhood of what I want but it has some flaws:

```
MATCH (dp:DataProduct {name: '1'})-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Table {name: 'X'})-[:HAS_COLUMN]->(c:Column {name: 'A'})
WITH dp,c,t
MATCH path = (sourceDataProduct:DataProduct)-[:CONTAINS]->(sourceTable:Table)-[:HAS_COLUMN]->(source:Column)-[:TRANSFORMATION*]->(c)
RETURN c.name as Target_Column, t.name as Target_Table, dp.name as Target_DataProduct,
       source.name as Source_Column, sourceTable.name as Source_Table, sourceDataProduct.name as Source_DataProduct,
       last(relationships(path)).type as Relationship_type,
       last(relationships(path)).code as Relationship_Code
```

But this query unfortunately returns this result:

| Target DataProduct | Target Table | Target Column | Source DataProduct | Source Table | Source Column | Relationship type | Relationship Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | A | 2 | Y | B | simple | insert |
| 1 | X | A | 3 | Z | C | simple | insert |

So I understand why this is going on, in my return statement I am putting dp, c and t as the first elements of a row, but I don't know how I can recursively reference here that what was the source in the first row, is now the target in the second. Also I am referencing the last element of the collection of relationships which is therefore also constant but should vary depending on where we are in the graph.

Alternatively it could also be that I don't add the targets in the result but rather make that implicit and add it in my application logic, but then I need to have the guarantee of the order of the results. Does Neo4j always return the results in the exact ordering how it traversed the graph? And of course I would still need to resolve the bit about the correct relationship being displayed in the correct row.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If your graph remains the same, the same query will yield the same output whenever it runs.

Comment: This was obviously only meant as an example, the graph will be dynamic. Also the starting point of the chain will vary between queries.

Comment: Yes, I get the point that there will be different target points, what I meant was if the path from the starting point, to the source data node, remains the same, the output will be the same, otherwise there will be some variations.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this query, but it may work for you:

```
MATCH path=(p:DataProduct)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Table)-[:HAS_COLUMN]->(c:Column)<-[:TRANSFORMATION*]-(rootSrc)
WHERE p.name = '1' AND t.name = 'X' AND c.name = 'A' AND NOT EXISTS((rootSrc)<-[:TRANSFORMATION]-())
WITH p, t, c,
  REDUCE(s=[], trans IN RELATIONSHIPS(path)[2..] |
    s + REDUCE(t=NULL, col IN [ENDNODE(trans)] |
      [(col)<-[:HAS_COLUMN]-(st)<-[:CONTAINS]-(sp)|{column:col.name, table:st.name, product:sp.name, type:trans.type, code: trans.code}]
    )
  ) AS srcList
UNWIND srcList AS srcElem
RETURN p, t, c, COLLECT(DISTINCT srcElem) AS sourceList
```

It should return the target product, table, and column as `p`, `t`, `c`; and a `sourceList` that contains maps of the following form in the correct source order:

```
{column:..., table:..., product:..., type:..., code:...}
```

The inner `REDUCE` is used as a hack to bind the `col` variable to each source column node so that we can use a [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension).

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! Unfortunately the query doesn't work, it just returns the DataProduct, Table and Column itself but not its upstream nodes. I have been able to work around this now by taking my query and just returning the path. I then manipulate the json in my backend to extract all the relevant information. Would have liked to do it more natively in Neo4j but this works as well and is good enough for my needs for now.

Comment: OK. But if you want to revisit this, update your question with some sample data to test with.